# Pycharm 2018.3 remote interpreter via WSL hangs

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Pycharm released update 2018.3 recently and I'm trying to get their remote interpreter via WSL to work. I've followed the steps on this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-wsl-as-a-remote-interpreter.html

Pycharm hangs when "getting remote interpreter version".

screenshot

[image: screenshot]

I checked the logs, and noticed it hangs when this command is ran:

2018-11-22 15:49:47,183 [ 106339]   INFO - .execution.wsl.WSLDistribution - [UBUNTU] Patched as: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu.exe run "cd \"/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2018.1.4/helpers\" && /usr/bin/python3 -V"

this is the log for a single session:

```
2018-11-22 15:48:00,844 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2018-11-22 15:48:00,883 [     39]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: PyCharm (build #PY-183.4284.139, 20 Nov 2018 11:00) 
2018-11-22 15:48:00,883 [     39]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64) 
2018-11-22 15:48:00,883 [     39]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b15 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2018-11-22 15:48:00,883 [     39]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.152-b15 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2018-11-22 15:48:00,886 [     42]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx2048m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Users\my_user\.PyCharm2018.3\config\pycharm64.exe.vmoptions -Didea.platform.prefix=Python -Dide.native.launcher=true -Didea.paths.selector=PyCharm2018.3 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\my_user\java_error_in_pycharm_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\my_user\java_error_in_pycharm.hprof 
2018-11-22 15:48:00,887 [     43]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\jre64\lib\ext: [access-bridge-64.jar, cldrdata.jar, dnsns.jar, jaccess.jar, jfxrt.jar, localedata.jar, meta-index, nashorn.jar, sunec.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, sunmscapi.jar, sunpkcs11.jar, zipfs.jar] 
2018-11-22 15:48:00,887 [     43]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - charsets: JNU=Cp1252 file=Cp1252 
2018-11-22 15:48:00,979 [    135]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 91 ms 
2018-11-22 15:48:00,983 [    139]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2018-11-22 15:48:01,149 [    305]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - User scale factor: 1.0 
2018-11-22 15:48:08,034 [   7190]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor javaee-specific.xml 
2018-11-22 15:48:08,063 [   7219]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor java-specific.xml 
2018-11-22 15:48:08,314 [   7470]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor js-nashorn-support.xml 
2018-11-22 15:48:08,664 [   7820]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor uml-java-support.xml 
2018-11-22 15:48:08,669 [   7825]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor uml-properties-support.xml 
2018-11-22 15:48:09,639 [   8795]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - CPU cores: 4; ForkJoinPool.commonPool: java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@780cf44e[Running, parallelism = 3, size = 0, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]; factory: com.intellij.concurrency.IdeaForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory@7ad13f14 
2018-11-22 15:48:09,725 [   8881]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - System scale factor: 1.0 (JRE-managed HiDPI) 
2018-11-22 15:48:10,684 [   9840]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor javaee-specific.xml 
2018-11-22 15:48:10,717 [   9873]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor java-specific.xml 
2018-11-22 15:48:10,950 [  10106]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor js-nashorn-support.xml 
2018-11-22 15:48:11,215 [  10371]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor uml-java-support.xml 
2018-11-22 15:48:11,219 [  10375]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor uml-properties-support.xml 
2018-11-22 15:48:11,457 [  10613]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin 'IdeaVim' can't be loaded because: Plugin is disabled 
2018-11-22 15:48:11,469 [  10625]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin 'IntelliJ Configuration Script' can't be loaded because: Plugin does not include any module dependency tags in its plugin.xml therefore is assumed legacy and can be loaded only in IntelliJ IDEA 
2018-11-22 15:48:11,475 [  10631]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin 'dotplugin' can't be loaded because: Plugin is disabled 
2018-11-22 15:48:11,831 [  10987]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 70 plugins initialized in 1467 ms 
2018-11-22 15:48:11,832 [  10988]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: AngularJS (183.4284.139), CSS Support (183.4284.139), CVS Integration (11), CoffeeScript (183.4284.139), Concurrency Visualiser (0.1), Copyright (8.1), Database Tools and SQL (183.4284.139), Django Database Support Integration (1.0), Docker integration (183.4284.139), EditorConfig (183.4284.139), File Watchers (183.4284.139), GNU GetText files support (*.po) (183.4284.139), Gherkin (999.999), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub (183.4284.139), HTML Tools (2.0), HTTP Client (183.4284.139), Haml (183.4284.139), IDE Settings Sync (183.4284.139), IDEA CORE (183.4284.139), IPython Notebook (0.1), Ini4Idea (183.4284.139), IntelliLang (8.0), JavaScript Debugger (1.0), JavaScript Intention Power Pack (0.9.4), JavaScript Support (1.0), Less support (183.4284.139), Markdown support (183.4284.139), Mercurial Integration (10.0), Perforce Integration (2.0), Properties Support (183.4284.139), Puppet Support (183.4284.139), Python BDD support for engines, based on Gherkin (cucumber, lettuce, behave) (0.1), Python Copyright (VERSION), Python Docker (VERSION), Python IntelliLang (VERSION), Python JavaScript Debugger Integration (VERSION), Python Localization Integration (VERSION), Python Profiler (0.1), Python ReStructureText Integration (1.0), Python Remote Interpreter (VERSION), Python Terminal (VERSION), Python UML Diagrams (VERSION), Python WSL Support (0.1), Python pytest-bdd support (0.1), ReStructuredText Support (183.4284.139), Remote Hosts Access (0.1), SSH Remote Run (0.1), Sass support (183.4284.139), Settings Repository (183.4284.139), Stylus support (999.999), Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TextMate bundles support (183.4284.139), Time Tracking (1.0), UML Support (1.0), Vagrant (183.4284.139), WSL Support Framework (183.4284.139), YAML (183.4284.139), tslint (183.4284.139) 
2018-11-22 15:48:11,832 [  10988]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded custom plugins: ANSI Highlighter (1.2.4), BashSupport (1.7.3), CSV Plugin (2.0.0), Ideolog (183.0.7.0), Zero Width Characters locator (0.93), doT (1.5.4) 
2018-11-22 15:48:11,832 [  10988]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Disabled plugins: IdeaVim (0.49), IntelliJ Configuration Script (183.4284.139), dotplugin (1.0.1) 
2018-11-22 15:48:12,610 [  11766]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === Start: JBA_NOT_CONNECTED === 
2018-11-22 15:48:12,777 [  11933]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=1994 
2018-11-22 15:48:12,852 [  12008]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\bin\fsnotifier64.exe 
2018-11-22 15:48:12,892 [  12048]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2018-11-22 15:48:13,722 [  12878]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=12, fontScale=0.0; restored: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0 
2018-11-22 15:48:15,297 [  14453]   INFO - til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized 
2018-11-22 15:48:15,447 [  14603]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
2018-11-22 15:48:15,472 [  14628]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2018-11-22 15:48:15,802 [  14958]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index exts enumerated:185, number of extensions:38 
2018-11-22 15:48:15,813 [  14969]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index scheduled:9 
2018-11-22 15:48:15,897 [  15053]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - All stub exts enumerated:67, number of extensions:95 
2018-11-22 15:48:15,898 [  15054]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - stub exts update scheduled:1 
2018-11-22 15:48:16,133 [  15289]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryValue - Registry value 'ide.ssh.one.time.password' has changed to 'true" 
2018-11-22 15:48:16,498 [  15654]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 1273 ms spent to cache options in application 
2018-11-22 15:48:16,498 [  15654]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider$Activity took 1273 ms 
2018-11-22 15:48:16,616 [  15772]   INFO -            PyTestLegacyInterop - Disabling com.jetbrains.python.testing.unittestLegacy.PythonUnitTestConfigurationProducer@25fa6865 
2018-11-22 15:48:16,617 [  15773]   INFO -            PyTestLegacyInterop - Disabling com.jetbrains.python.testing.pytestLegacy.PyTestConfigurationProducer@adeca1f 
2018-11-22 15:48:16,617 [  15773]   INFO -            PyTestLegacyInterop - Disabling com.jetbrains.python.testing.nosetestLegacy.PythonNoseTestConfigurationProducer@6e980664 
2018-11-22 15:48:16,657 [  15813]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - 77 application components initialized in 6299ms 
2018-11-22 15:48:16,750 [  15906]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 19387 ms 
2018-11-22 15:48:17,753 [  16909]   INFO - m.intellij.ui.mac.touchbar.NST - OS doesn't support touchbar, skip nst loading 
2018-11-22 15:48:19,479 [  18635]   INFO - ndex.PrebuiltIndexProviderBase - Using prebuilt id-index from C:\Users\my_user\.PyCharm2018.3\system\index\.persistent\prebuilt\Python\id-index.input 
2018-11-22 15:48:21,880 [  21036]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [] - [<Project>] 
2018-11-22 15:48:21,887 [  21043]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [Git] - [C:/Repos/gitlabs/app-django] 
2018-11-22 15:48:21,887 [  21043]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [Git] - [C:/Repos/gitlabs/app-django/ldlib] 
2018-11-22 15:48:23,267 [  22423]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0; restored: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0 
2018-11-22 15:48:23,273 [  22429]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0; restored: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0 
2018-11-22 15:48:23,324 [  22480]   INFO - pl$FileIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done:7510 
2018-11-22 15:48:24,393 [  23549]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done:1068 
2018-11-22 15:48:25,515 [  24671]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 112 project components initialized in 7033 ms 
2018-11-22 15:48:26,124 [  25280]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader took 9617 ms 
2018-11-22 15:48:27,178 [  26334]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 1 module(s) loaded in 1660 ms 
2018-11-22 15:48:27,642 [  26798]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
2018-11-22 15:48:28,038 [  27194]   INFO - rojectCodeStyleSettingsManager - Initialized from default code style settings. 
2018-11-22 15:48:28,277 [  27433]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader took 2151 ms 
2018-11-22 15:48:28,286 [  27442]   INFO - om.intellij.util.ProfilingUtil - Profiling agent is not enabled. Add -agentlib:yjpagent to idea.vmoptions if necessary to profile IDEA. 
2018-11-22 15:48:30,075 [  29231]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 15 project components initialized in 34 ms 
2018-11-22 15:48:30,358 [  29514]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - EditorHistoryManagerStartUpActivity run in 334ms under project opening modal progress 
2018-11-22 15:48:30,448 [  29604]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionPreloader took 2169 ms 
2018-11-22 15:48:30,618 [  29774]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.ide.actions.GotoClassPresentationUpdater took 167 ms 
2018-11-22 15:48:31,074 [  30230]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing Python language level to 7 roots in 1 SDKs took 1125ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2018-11-22 15:48:33,645 [  32801]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - OpenFilesActivity run in 3268ms under project opening modal progress 
2018-11-22 15:48:33,949 [  33105]   INFO - llij.database.util.SqlDialects - SQL dialects initialized in 1 s 349 ms 
2018-11-22 15:48:33,960 [  33116]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - JsbtStartupActivity run in 112ms under project opening modal progress 
2018-11-22 15:48:33,971 [  33127]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Post-startup activities under progress took 4162ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 2/4 sluggish, 1/4 very slow 
2018-11-22 15:48:34,931 [  34087]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === Start.updateInitStatus === 
2018-11-22 15:48:34,945 [  34101]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === StatusBar.update create === 
2018-11-22 15:48:34,960 [  34116]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === calculateInitStatus === 
2018-11-22 15:48:35,215 [  34371]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 2661ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 1/2 sluggish, 1/2 very slow 
2018-11-22 15:48:36,045 [  35201]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 766 ms spent on EDT to cache options in application 
2018-11-22 15:48:36,127 [  35283]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - C:/Repos/gitlabs/app-django/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
2018-11-22 15:48:36,262 [  35418]   INFO - .cloudConfig.CloudConfigClient - === Get cloud config URL: https://cloudconfig.jetbrains.com/cloudconfig/files === 
2018-11-22 15:48:36,401 [  35557]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - [.] git version 
2018-11-22 15:48:36,745 [  35901]   INFO - Json.PackageJsonUpdateNotifier - processPackageJsonFiles [] 
2018-11-22 15:48:36,857 [  36013]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === calculateInitStatus.value: JBA_NOT_CONNECTED === 
2018-11-22 15:48:37,286 [  36442]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 19103 ms 
2018-11-22 15:48:37,477 [  36633]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === End.updateInitStatus === 
2018-11-22 15:48:38,532 [  37688]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - git version 2.8.1.windows.1 
2018-11-22 15:48:38,842 [  37998]   INFO - ea.config.GitExecutableManager - Git version for C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe : 2.8.1 
2018-11-22 15:48:39,806 [  38962]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [Git] - [C:/Repos/gitlabs/app-django] 
2018-11-22 15:48:39,810 [  38966]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [Git] - [C:/Repos/gitlabs/app-django/ldlib] 
2018-11-22 15:48:39,966 [  39122]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 4747ms; general responsiveness: 1/5 sluggish; EDT responsiveness: 1/5 sluggish 
2018-11-22 15:48:40,608 [  39764]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 423 ms spent to cache options in project 
2018-11-22 15:48:40,608 [  39764]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Some post-startup activities freeze UI for noticeable time. Please consider making them DumbAware to do them in background under modal progress, or just making them faster to speed up project opening. 
2018-11-22 15:48:40,608 [  39764]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Activity run in 423ms on UI thread 
2018-11-22 15:48:40,705 [  39861]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === StatusBar.start another widget: com.intellij.cloudConfig.StatusBarInfoManager$InfoComponent@47298084 === 
2018-11-22 15:48:41,295 [  40451]   INFO - j.ide.plugins.RepositoryHelper - using cached plugin list (updated at 11/22/2018 2:44 PM) 
2018-11-22 15:48:42,130 [  41286]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 562 ms spent on EDT to cache options in project 
2018-11-22 15:48:47,465 [  46621]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - shell environment loaded (49 vars) 
2018-11-22 15:48:48,154 [  47310]   INFO - ns.python.sdk.PythonSdkUpdater - Updating sys.path took 2614 ms 
2018-11-22 15:48:48,157 [  47313]   INFO - ns.python.sdk.PythonSdkUpdater - Bogus sys.path entry C:\Repos\Bitbucket\python_venvs\venv_python3.7_x86\Scripts\python37.zip 
2018-11-22 15:48:48,234 [  47390]   INFO - ns.python.sdk.PythonSdkUpdater - Binary skeletons directory for SDK Python 3.7 (venv_python3.7_x86) (C:\Repos\Bitbucket\python_venvs\venv_python3.7_x86\Scripts\python.exe)): C:/Users/my_user/.PyCharm2018.3/system/python_stubs/1298413135 
2018-11-22 15:48:48,234 [  47390]   INFO - ns.python.sdk.PythonSdkUpdater - User skeletons directory for SDK Python 3.7 (venv_python3.7_x86) (C:\Repos\Bitbucket\python_venvs\venv_python3.7_x86\Scripts\python.exe)): C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2018.1.4/helpers/python-skeletons 
2018-11-22 15:48:48,300 [  47456]   INFO - ns.python.sdk.PythonSdkUpdater - Performing background update of skeletons for SDK Python 3.7 (venv_python3.7_x86) (C:\Repos\Bitbucket\python_venvs\venv_python3.7_x86\Scripts\python.exe) 
2018-11-22 15:48:48,305 [  47461]   INFO - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - Refreshing skeletons for C:\Repos\Bitbucket\python_venvs\venv_python3.7_x86\Scripts\python.exe 
2018-11-22 15:48:59,345 [  58501]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.ansorgit.plugins.bash.editor.codecompletion.PreloadPathCompletionActivity took 28707 ms 
2018-11-22 15:49:07,284 [  66440]   INFO - .skeletons.PySkeletonGenerator - Retrieving binary module list took 18540 ms 
2018-11-22 15:49:07,289 [  66445]   INFO - tPregeneratedSkeletonsProvider - Home path is C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4 
2018-11-22 15:49:07,290 [  66446]   INFO - tPregeneratedSkeletonsProvider - Pregenerated skeletons root is C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\skeletons 
2018-11-22 15:49:07,291 [  66447]   INFO - tPregeneratedSkeletonsProvider - Found pre-generated skeletons at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\skeletons\skeletons-win-402-python-3.7.0.zip 
2018-11-22 15:49:07,805 [  66961]   INFO - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - Rebuilding skeletons for binaries took 505 ms 
2018-11-22 15:49:08,989 [  68145]   INFO - ns.python.sdk.PythonSdkUpdater - Performing background scan of packages for SDK Python 3.7 (venv_python3.7_x86) (C:\Repos\Bitbucket\python_venvs\venv_python3.7_x86\Scripts\python.exe) 
2018-11-22 15:49:08,994 [  68150]   INFO - packaging.PyPackageManagerImpl - Running packaging tool: C:\Repos\Bitbucket\python_venvs\venv_python3.7_x86\Scripts\python.exe C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\packaging_tool.py list 
2018-11-22 15:49:11,474 [  70630]   INFO - hon.packaging.PyPIPackageCache - Loaded 159284 packages from C:\Users\my_user\.PyCharm2018.3\system\python_packages\pypi-cache.json 
2018-11-22 15:49:22,800 [  81956]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - git log took 15282 ms. Command parameters: 
cmd.exe /c start /b /low /wait  "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false -c diff.renameLimit=1000 log --no-walk=unsorted --stdin --pretty=format:%x01%x01%H%x02%x02%ct%x02%x02%an%x02%x02%at%x02%x02%ae%x02%x02%cn%x02%x02%ce%x02%x02%P%x02%x02%s%x02%x02%b%x02%x02%B%x03%x03 --encoding=UTF-8 -M --name-status -m -- 
2018-11-22 15:49:25,367 [  84523]   INFO - packaging.PyPackageManagerImpl - Running packaging tool: C:\Repos\Bitbucket\python_venvs\venv_python3.7_x86\Scripts\python.exe C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\packaging_tool.py list 
2018-11-22 15:49:47,182 [ 106338]   INFO - .execution.wsl.WSLDistribution - [UBUNTU] Patching: /usr/bin/python3 -V; working dir: /mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2018.1.4/helpers; envs: : without sudo 
2018-11-22 15:49:47,183 [ 106339]   INFO - .execution.wsl.WSLDistribution - [UBUNTU] Patched as: C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu.exe run "cd \"/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2018.1.4/helpers\" && /usr/bin/python3 -V" 
2018-11-22 15:51:47,938 [ 227094]   WARN - n.process.BaseOSProcessHandler - Process hasn't generated any output for a long time.
If it's a long-running mostly idle daemon process, consider overriding OSProcessHandler#readerOptions with 'BaseOutputReader.Options.forMostlySilentProcess()' to reduce CPU usage.
Command line: C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu.exe run "cd \"/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2018.1.4/helpers\" && /usr/bin/python3 -V" 
java.lang.Throwable: Process creation:
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler.<init>(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:34)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.OSProcessHandler.<init>(OSProcessHandler.java:89)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.OSProcessHandler.<init>(OSProcessHandler.java:44)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.KillableProcessHandler.<init>(KillableProcessHandler.java:48)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ColoredProcessHandler.<init>(ColoredProcessHandler.java:38)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.KillableColoredProcessHandler.<init>(KillableColoredProcessHandler.java:38)
    at com.jetbrains.python.run.PythonProcessHandler.<init>(PythonProcessHandler.java:37)
    at com.jetbrains.python.run.PythonProcessHandler.<init>(PythonProcessHandler.java:33)
    at com.jetbrains.python.wsl.PyWSLProcessHandler.<init>(PyWSLProcessHandler.kt:16)
    at com.jetbrains.python.wsl.PyWSLUtilsKt.startWslProcess(PyWSLUtils.kt:73)
    at com.jetbrains.python.wsl.PyWSLUtilsKt.startWslProcess$default(PyWSLUtils.kt:53)
    at com.jetbrains.python.wsl.PyWSLRemoteProcessStarterManager.startRemoteProcess(PyWSLRemoteProcessStarterManager.kt:22)
    at com.jetbrains.python.wsl.PyWSLRemoteProcessStarterManager.executeRemoteProcess(PyWSLRemoteProcessStarterManager.kt:34)
    at com.jetbrains.python.remote.PyRemoteInterpreterUtil$1.run(PyRemoteInterpreterUtil.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:727)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:442)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:582)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$null$10(ApplicationImpl.java:592)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I also ran that command from cmd and i get: Python 3.6.7, which leaves me clueless as to why it hangs there.

My specs:

OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise

Version 10.0.16299 Build 16299

System Type x64-based PC

Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2701 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)

Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 16.0 GB

Comment: Please file an issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY), the developer who is responsible for the WSL support would help

Comment: @user2235698 Thanks for the suggestion. An issue was filed not long after posting this question here. Here's the link https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32923

Comment: Similar issue here with remote development in Pycharm over SSH. Sometimes hangs. Where are the internal pycharm logs are stored in Ubuntu?